# RESTful API: is it appropriate to make POST request without data

Tags: rest

I'm working on service that collects prices from third-party online shop. I use RESTful API to add new product id and get price by id.

To add new product:
`POST /product/12345` (parses product page and stores price to db)

To update stored price:
`PUT /product/12345` (parses product page and updates price in db)

To get price:
`GET /product/12345` (return price from db if data exists)

My question is am I doing it right way (especially with POST verb)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a new `product`, `POST` to the collection resource `/product`:

```
POST /product/
```

The server will assign an ID to the new Product and return it.

```
201 Created
Location: http://example.com/product/9876
```

**Edit:**

If you already know the ID, create the product using `PUT`:

```
PUT /product/9876
```

Comment: I know product id when I do POST. For example for http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004I3WB5M/ id is B004I3WB5M.

Answer (score 4):

Normally the API calls for the Post : Data will not be placed on the url, which can be mentioned like below

To add new product: `POST /product/new`

Thanks,
SVN